# Abrir ventana con Waze

Tags: html, html5

Es posible en una pagina web hacer click en un botón y que este abra en una ventana nueva la pagina de Waze con el punto de destino.

Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya encontre la solucion.  Es utilizar el siguiente iframe de Waze en una landing page

```
<iframe src="https://embed.waze.com/iframe?zoom=12&lat=45.6906304&lon=-120.810983&pin=1"
  width="300" height="400"></iframe>
```

Tiene los siguientes parametros:

zoom: de 3 a 17
 lat: latitud
 lon: longitud
 pin: centrer el punto en el mapa

La documentacion esta en el siguiente link: 
https://developers.google.com/waze/iframe/?hl=es